# Responsive horizontal menu for mobile

Tags: user-interface, responsive-design, user-experience, mobile-website

I'm thinking this is probably a bad question or I'm overthinking, but I did a responsive horizontal menu without a collapse bar for mobile. Is this a really bad design idea? I used flexbox and it is responsive for most devices that I tested.

Should I make it a collapsible navbar like most sites? And if it is a bad idea, why?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you have only four items, you are good.
A collapsed menu is always a bad idea since menu items are hiding behind it.
If you want to make it more user friendly, put the menu at the bottom, to look like more like an app (at the tip of the thumb).

Comment: there are 7 items, actually. but menu seems responsive for all devices I tested...

Comment: if a collapsed menu is a bad idea, why most sites use it? bootstrap?

Comment: Hard to tell why, but by common sense, you can figure out that it's always better to have visible navbar items than hidden. 
I'll give you just a few reasons: 
a) User must go one extra step to accomplish the task
b) User is not sure what is behind the dropdown
c)  Some dropdown designs are not too apparent, so users can easily miss it. 
d) We are talking about navigation, so easy access is a must! 
Envision you want to drive a car but the steering wheel is hidden somewhere in a glovebox. 
Did you get my point?